# build getting failed for ios xcode build -flutter app

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode, flutter-dependencies

Native assets file /Users/yashwanthkalimi/Desktop/CMP/craft_my_plate_client/.dart_tool/flutter_build/55f73a0f456c61786ce839bc0c36796b/native_assets.yaml doesn't exist.

I have done flutter clean , deleted ios folder, deleted and updated pods for many times still getting the same issue. What to do now.

Comment: check the flutter_build/55f73* folder, are the files navite_assets.d, native_assets.stamp and native_assets.yaml really not there? Remove the whoel .dart_tool folder as its just generated, try again to build the project

Comment: Multiple commands produce '/Users/yashwanthkalimi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cxvdaqxdpgecbigstkvxdoegtwbw/Build/Products/Debug-prod-iphonesimulator/Craft My Plate.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'---
 i am getting this error. can you help me

Comment: your GoogleService-Info.plist should be located under ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist. This file is created or needed if you use google services like firebase. Also flutter firebase cli would generate the file holding your information for firebase. Check if you configured your firebase project properly